# How to setup up VCS in android studio

Tags: android, version-control, android-studio

I am new to android Studio.I just had few questions.
1-What is VCS about what does it do??
2-How to integrate it in android studio??

Please help me sort out my doubts

Answer (score 0):

There is a drop-down menu labeled VCS. On the dropdown-menu, select enable version control integration.

VCS' are used to track changes in  source code. They make it easy to distributively collaborate on code. Additionally, they let you track the changes in your source code, in case you break things and want to roll back changes.

Comment: can u give me with the detailed step how to do it??

Comment: `git init` in the folder of your project. When you've made significant changes `git commit -m "message"` to file a change. That is enough to get you started. You should use the command line for this instead of android studio because you'll learn a lot more by using the underlying commands.